# customize feathers' drawers list

Tags: list, actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am using feathers ui components for starling to create an app which has drawers as navigation menu.these drawers have feathers list as data providers. There are particular elements on this list that need to be unique, that is they must have a unique font color to distinguish them from the rest.
so my question is: is there a way to customize the look of specific elements within the same list? Say, a list with 4 elements, each one has its own font color.
Thanks a lot for your help in advance, any comment could be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. I've done it an year ago, but things shouldn't be that different. You must set appropriate let's call it `type` within the data you pass to the item renderer, Then you create custom item renderer, which has init and update function. There, you can check what's the type and construct the view differently - change font or whatever you want.

And here are some nice readings on the topic, which will definately help you: http://feathersui.com/help/item-renderers.html